# PHP fetch_object() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
$id = $_POST["id"];
$id2 = $_POST["id2"];

$db = new mysqli('localhost', '***', '***', '***');

if (mysqli_connect_errno() == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chat_message WHERE id > " . $id . " AND id <= " . $id2 . " ORDER BY id";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    while ($msg = $result->fetch_object()) {
        ?>

        <div>...</div>

        <?php
    }
}

$db->close();
?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in /var/www/template/loadchat.php on line 11
```

Line 11:

```
while ($msg = $result->fetch_object())
```

Any help? Because I work on this thing since yesterday and I can't find the mistake.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi, why not use prepared statements? Especially as your code is highly susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: add `echo $db->error;` after `$result = $db->query($sql);` to see the error.

Comment: This code is dangerously insecure. Since you're using `mysqli`, you **must** use [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to ensure you're escaping everything properly.

Answer (score 3):

`$result = $db->query($sql);` is returning false. This means that the query failed for some reason.

Quoting the PHP manual for [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

To check for an error you can do:

```
if (!$db->query($sql)) {
    trigger_error('Database error: '. $db->error);
}
```

Comment: How can I see what's failing?

Comment: @user1994929, try executing it directly to the server, via phpmyadmin for example.

Comment: @user - Print out the error you're getting back. After `$db->query()`, do `echo $db->error;`.

Comment: @user1994929, what does `var_dump($db->error);` prints after the query?

Comment: missing a dot for concatenation... trigger_error('Database error: ' . $db->error);

Comment: @Jefffrey and thank you for your post, helped me debug something :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Verify if your db table is named like `chat_message` (maybe it is `chat_messages`?)

2) Verify if your `chat_message.id` field exists

3) Verify if your php variables `$id` and `$id2` are integer/float numbers!

Comment: 1) Yes it is named chat_message, and I can see entries.

Comment: Then the problem is for sure in your `$id` and `$id2` variables.. make an echo before your query to see what values they have

Comment: You should also try to put some `'` in your query for that values: `"SELECT * FROM chat_message WHERE id > '" . $id . "' AND id <= '" . $id2 . "' ORDER BY id"`

Comment: I can't do "echo" because I am working with $.ajax, so it loads the chat instead of echo ... .

Comment: You should use firebug (Firefox plugin) to see what is ajax sending and what is retrieving..